# Is there a way to take a synchronous method that may or may not return a value and add it to a List<Func<Task>>?

Tags: c#, task, action, func

In the process of refactoring some legacy code at work and part of it is to convert an instance of `List<Action>` to `List<Func<Task>>`. Elsewhere in the codebase, there are several instances of something along the lines of this:

```
entity.Tasks.Add(() => 
{
    _service.Process(operation)
}
```

The above would work fine when the Tasks property was `List<Action>`, but gives errors when turned into `List<Func<Task>>` with no obvious way to fix it.

I know next to nothing about Func, Task, Action, asynchronous/synchronous programming, particularly in C#. Any help provided is immensely appreciated or even just a referral to information where I could find the information needed to solve this myself.

Comment: Gives errors? Which errors?

Comment: "Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<Task>'" is the error I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to create a function that returns a Task. A solution could be creating a task that internally executes your synchronous code and then add it to the list. Like this:

```
entity.Tasks.Add(() => Task.Run(_service.Process(operation)));
```

Just note that the code only creates a function that returns a Task but the Task won't be executed until you ask for it.

Here is more info about the topic:

- [Task.Run Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run)
- [Task-based Asynchronous Programming in C#](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asynchronous-programming-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick primer...

`List<Action>` says: I'm a list that accepts a method with no input parameters and returns `void` when invoked.

`List<Func<Task>>` says: I'm a list that accepts a method with no input parameters and returns a `Task` when invoked.

*Note: I'm using the term "method" to represent a named method, delegate, lambda, etc...*

For your case, `entity.Tasks` was originally defined as `List<Action>`; but is now defined as `List<Func<Task>>`.

Given the case where you need to take the legacy methods which return no value (void), you could create a shimming method which returns a task after completing the `Action` from the original method.

For Example...

```cs
static Task Shim( Action action )
{
    action();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// the above will wrap a method that does not return a value such as:
static void DoWork( string str )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( str );
}
```

You can now use the `Shim` to add to your new collection type. For example...

```cs
var list = new List<Func<Task>>();

// add the Shim to the list
list.Add( () => Shim( () => DoWork( "I'm a shim" ) ));
```

In your use case, it will look something like this:

```cs
entity.Tasks.Add(() => 
{
    return Shim( () => _service.Process(operation) );
}

// or a bit more shorthanded:
entity.Tasks.Add( () => Shim( () => _service.Process(operation) ));
```

As pointed out in the comments, the `Shim` path is less than ideal since the new version really should be wrapped in a `Task` to be more inline with how Tasks and Exceptions get wrapped up.

Here's an example of wrapping the legacy code into the new version without any shims:

```cs
entity.Tasks.Add( () => Task.Run( () => _service.Process(operation) ));
```

Comment: The `Shim` method doesn't have the ideal error behavior. In case the `action` fails, the exception will be thrown synchronously instead of being stored in the resulting `Task`.

Comment: Agreed. The `Shim` would retain the same behavior as the legacy version. I'll add another option to wrap the legacy `Action` in a task.

Answer (score -2):

Actions are your void methods that don't return a response. Your tasks collection is expecting a returned task. You can wrap the _service.Process(operation) with a task and within the task, run the _service.Process, then return something like

return Task.FromResult(false);